# li:not(.classname):first-child selector is not selecting

Tags: css, css-selectors

i am having the following list

```
<ul>
  <li class="item-header">header</li>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
</ul>
```

i want to select `<li>item1</li>` only and assign padding to it using the following selector.. here is what my css does:

```
  li:not(.item-header):first-child {
    padding-top: 2em;
  }
```

and it's not selecting anything. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Tried `ul li:nth-child(2)`?

Comment: there might not be item-header at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:first-child` pseudo class doesn't work that way. It isn't working as you expect because that element isn't the first child.

To cover instances where the first child does have the class `item-header`, select the succeeding `li` element through usage of the adjacent sibling combinator, `+`.

```
li:not(.item-header):first-child,
li.item-header:first-child + li {
    padding-top: 2em;
}
```

This should work as expected now - [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/rcLFH/).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you're telling your CSS to look for:

- a `li` that hasn't the `.item-header` class

***AND***

- the first item of the list

The first item of your list **HAS** the class. So nothing happens.

**[A little check.](http://jsfiddle.net/eT8Hw/)**

You rule does work only in the first example I made because that `li` confirm the rule you made.

The good way to do that is reported in **[Josh Crozier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23817866/2600397)**